# SQL Server Index and EF Core (2.2) Index

Tags: entity-framework-core

When defining a index manually in SQL Server (via CREATE INDEX statement) and not specifying this index in the EFCore DBContext (we're using v2.2 and the Fluent API), will the index be considered anyway or what effect does specifying the index in EF Core have when generating SQL queries etc.? I'm not really sure what the real effect is from a technical point of view.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The short answer is - none. It's used only by migrations. Runtime query behavior is not affected in any way if you define or not define index in the EF Core model metadata.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, Could you post it as an answer? Then I can close it by accepting the answer.

Comment: Sure, there you go.

Answer (score 0):

[Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations) in general are just part of the physical database (store) model and do no affect the runtime behavior of EF Core (except of course the PK, but it is special anyway and unique index/constraint is assumed regardless of whether it actually exists). The primary (and only) case for having index related fluent API/data annotations currently is to be able to generate physical database schema with migrations.

It's partially mentioned in the [Indexes part of the Performance topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-querying#use-indexes-properly) of the official EF Core documentation:

> As a general rule, there isn't any special EF knowledge to using indexes or diagnosing performance issues related to them; general database knowledge related to indexes is just as relevant to EF applications as to applications not using EF.